# Why doesn't this xsl:sort selector work?

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Things>
  <Thing>
    <Thing ID="0002"/>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Thing ID="0003"/>
    <Name>Alice</Name>
  </Thing>
  <Thing>
    <Thing ID="0001"/>
    <Name>Carol</Name>
  </Thing>
</Things>
```

I want to output the same XML sorted by the ID attribute. The following stylesheet does what I want. The commented-out `xsl:sort` (and several variations that I tried) doesn't work -- I just get an unsorted copy of the original document. (And no error messages.)

How can I specifically select the ID attribute on the Thing element (to avoid using ID attributes on other elements that may be present in a larger document)?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Things">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates>
       <xsl:sort select="*/@ID" data-type="number"/>

       <!-- I don't understand why this doesn't work:

         <xsl:sort select="Thing/Thing[@ID]" data-type="number"/>
       -->
     </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
    <xsl:sort select="Thing/@ID" data-type="number"/>
```

At the point where this occurs, the context is already at each first-level `Thing`, so the sort key is the @ID attribute of the second-level Thing.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. To explain further, @bst, the difference between `Thing/@ID` and `Thing[@ID]` is that the former means 'the `ID` attribute of a `Thing` element', while the latter means 'a `Thing` element that has an `ID` attribute' (glossing over some small details for the sake of simplity).